Listing the Tables in the Storage Account using ADF Web Activity is failed with an authorization error
i have added the parameter source storage account sas token as shown below:

Then I added web activity to list the tables of the storage account where this account has only 500 tables but i'm getting authentication failed error:

Web Activity - ListTables
URL: @concat('https://srcstoreacc131.table.core.windows.net/Tables', pipeline().parameters.sourceSAS)
Headers: Accept-application/json # Add as dynamic content value
Method: GET

Error:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<error xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
  <code>AuthenticationFailed</code>
  <message xml:lang="en-US">Server failed to authenticate the request. Make sure the value of Authorization header is formed correctly including the signature.
Time:2024-04-23T12:32:02.1385780Z</message>
</error>


Make sure you have provided correct SAS. While generating SAS give following permission as shown below:

Provide web activity URL as mentioned below:
@concat('https://<storageAccountName>.table.core.windows.net/Tables',pipeline().parameters.SAS)

Configure web activity as shown below:

You will be able to list the tables successfully as shown below:

For more information you can refer to the MS document.
